# How to authenticate my JWT token in django-rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt

I implemented JWT Token Authentication in Django rest framework, It gets me token but the problem I am getting is I am not able to authenticate it on the pages which need authentication.

I tried "Authorization: Bearer " after that authenticated url,

I tried "Authorization : JWT Token  token"

Comment: where do you put ~I tried "Authorization : JWT Token token"~ it should be in the headers of your json request

Comment: I put it lke this <http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list/12/ "Authorization : JWT Token token">

Comment: The URL and then the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

JWT token it is used for API authentication only and it should be the javascript or the client side code which handle the API will be used. for example if you use axios in javascript framework you will be putting the token in the api header like this

```
let config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: Bearer <my_token>,
  }
}
axios.post(URL, config).then(...)
```

so if you want to do the authentication in the api and let yourclient code or javascript handle the logic of the authenticate page instead

Comment: But I doens't work when I send the data from python requests

Comment: you have to use api 
import requests
import json

url = '{YOUR URL}'
payload = {
    your payload
}
# Adding empty header as parameters are being sent in payload
headers = {    "Authorization": "{token}"}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.content)